What should one do if he thinks an accepted answer is incorrect?
I was wondering what is the appropriate action if you participate in a question, you see an answer that is incorrect/incomplete, yet this answer is marked as an accepted answer.
The person who asked the question might be happy with it, but having it displayed as the "right" answer might be problematic for later readers who could then be fooled by mistaken information.

Downvote and leave a comment. Unfortunately, the accepted answer cannot be deleted, so even if the author realizes his mistake he can't do anything beyond edit.

I agree, I see this all the time.  I would also leave your own answer.
